# How force www except url

Tags: .htaccess

Use code force https with www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

How do I make the url below work both with WWW and without WWW

```
https://example.com/license/get_license.php
https://example.com/license/verified_license.php
```

Comment: Using httpd.conf `ServerName example.com` `ServerAlias www.example.com`

Comment: I have an old version of a system that has these urls without the www. When I made this change, an error occurred when I placed www. For now I have to have these two models

Comment: What is exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Resolution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/license/get_license\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/license/verified_license\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Credits: Hosting Webfaction